# How to rewrite GCD code as POSIX in C

Tags: c, multithreading, macos, unix, posix

This question is a follow-up to a question which happened to be more complex than I had initially thought would be. In a program I'm writing the main thread takes care of GUI-driven data updates, a producer thread (with a number of sub-threads, because the producer task is "embarrassingly parallel") writes to the circular buffer, while the real-time consumer thread reads from it. Original platform of development was OSX/Darwin, but I'd like to make the code more portable, UNIX source compatible. Everything can easily be written in POSIX, except for the following OSX-specific **GCD command for which I can't estimate a POSIX equivalent, if any**. It launches the producer thread, from which its subthreads are being launched programmatically, depending on the number of available logical CPU cores:

```
void dproducer (bool on, int cpuNum, uData* data)
{
    if (on == true)
    {
    data->state = starting;
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
            producerSum(on, cpuNum, data);
        });
    }
return;
}
```

This is the block diagram of the program:

[image]

For clarity I'm also adding the producerSum code. It's an infinite loop whose execution can either wait for the consumer thread to do the work, or get interrupted by changing data->state, which has global scope:

```
void producerSum(bool on, int cpuNum, uData* data)
{
int rc;
pthread_t threads[cpuNum]; //subthreads
tData thread_args[cpuNum];
void* resulT;
static float frames  [4096];

while(on){
    memset(frames,  0, 4096*sizeof(float));
   if( (fbuffW  = (float**)calloc(cpuNum + 1, sizeof(float*)))!= NULL)
      for (int i=0; i<cpuNum; ++i){
        fbuffW[i] = (float*)calloc(data->frames, sizeof(float));
        thread_args[i].tid = i;           //ord. number of thread
        thread_args[i].cpuCount = cpuNum; //counter increment step
        thread_args[i].data = data;
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, producerTN, (void *) &thread_args[i]);
        if(rc != 0)printf("rc = %s\n",strerror(rc));
      }        
    for (int i=0; i<cpuNum; ++i) rc = pthread_join(threads[i], &resulT);
    //each subthread writes to fbuffW[i] and results get summed
    for(UInt32 samp = 0; samp < data->frames; samp++)
        for(int i = 0; i < cpuNum; i++)
            frames[samp] += fbuffW[i][samp];

    switch (data->state) { ... } //graceful interruption, resuming and termination mechanism

    { … } //simple code for copying frames[] to the circular buffer

    pthread_cond_wait (&cond, &mutex);//wait for the real-time consumer

    for(int i = 0; i < cpuNum; i++) free(fbuffW[i]); free(fbuffW);
} //end while(on)    
return;
}
```

The syncing inside the producer thread is being successfully handled by ***pthread_create( )*** and ***pthread_join( )***, while necessary coordination between the producer and consumer threads is being successfully handled by a variable of ***pthread_mutex_t*** and a variable of ***pthread_cond_t***  (with corresponding locking, unlocking, broadcasting and waiting commands). uData is a program defined struct (or class instance). Any direction where to look at would help indeed.

Thanks for reading this post!

Comment: Note that libdispatch (i.e. GCD) is open source, and there is currently extensive work to make sure it is portable to all Swift-supported platforms (particularly Linux). If your needs aren't immediate, and you're just trying to move towards more portable code, you may do better to follow that project than reimplement everything. https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch This may be much better than reimplementing your already-working code.

Comment: Probably this article can be useful: http://newosxbook.com/articles/GCD.html

Comment: Thanks, this is very good news for Linux and Swift and open source, since GCD is really great when one does not need custom threading and thread pools. Yet I'd prefer keeping **away** from **Swift** and libdispatch and rather stay with the topic. I don't have to reimplement everything, just one command, since everything else is fully functional in POSIX.  "Everything" is no more than 500 lines of code. Thanks, the newosxbook.com/articles/GCD.html is known to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dispatch queue is just what it sounds like: a queue, as in the standard FIFO list data structure. It holds tasks. Those tasks can be represented by Objective-C Blocks as in your code or by function pointers and context pointer values. You'll presumably need to avoid Blocks if you're aiming for cross-platform compatibility. In fact, since you only ever dispatch one task, your tasks can just encapsulate the parameters (`on`, `cpuNum`, and `data`) and not the code (the call to `producerSum()`).

The queues are serviced by threads from a thread pool. GCD manages the threads and pool. At least on OS X, there's integration with the OS such that the pool's size is governed by overall system load, which you won't be able to reproduce in a cross-platform manner.

Operations on a dispatch queue are thread-safe. This includes adding tasks to them and the worker threads removing tasks from them.

You're going to have to implement all of this. It's definitely possible, but it will be a bother. In many ways, the queues and the thread pool constitute a producer-consumer architecture. Basically, your GCD-based solution was a bit of a cheat because you just used a producer-consumer API to implement your producer-consumer design. Now, you're going to have to really implement a producer-consumer design without the crutch.

There's basically no more to it than the thread-creation and POSIX condition variables you're already using.

`dispatch_async()` is basically just locking the mutex for the queue of tasks, adding the task to the queue, signalling the condition variable, and unlocking the mutex. Each worker thread will just wait on the condition variable and, when it wakes, lock the mutex, pop a task off the queue if there's one, unlock the mutex, and run the task if it got one. You probably also need a mechanism to signal the worker thread that it's time to gracefully terminate.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my question and accepting that I'm asking it for a reason. I've also always felt my dealing with GCD had been a quick fix with a bit of cheating for doing something great without really knowing what I'm doing. The **work** is "embarrassingly parallel" and 2-24 subthreads are clones: integrators with counter offsets. It would be meaningless to coordinate them otherwise, because they are **not indepenent**. I've added the producerSum code to the question. All I need is learning how to get rid of the "block" which "spawns" the queue from the main thread.

Comment: Queues aren't spawned. All `dispatch_async()` does it put a task on a list. As I said, there's an automatic thread pool which services the tasks on the list. If you have been thinking of `dispatch_async()` as just "run this in a separate thread" and not really relying on the list nature of the queue or the thread pool management of GCD, then you can replace it with `pthread_create()`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently working on an 8-core and a 16-core machine. I've slightly rewritten the `producerSum()` call to make it pthread-compliant, following your advice to write a regular `pthread_create` in `dproducer()`. Looks **shamelessly simple**, and passes the tests so far - I still need a bit more time to implement this in a real-life program. BTW, is there a piece of literature where I can learn more on writing portable UNIX dispatch queues while dealing with real-time threads, that you could recommend?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of any literature like that.